# Combining two input tags like a single input

Tags: html

I'm new to HTML and I have some questions regarding input tags.
Here I have two inputs seperated by a span tag(-). What I want to do is to wrap two inputs like a single input like the image below.
Do I need to add styles using css or change the whole structure of the code?

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="form-realname" class="col">test*</label>
    <div class="input-group col">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" />
        <span class="input-group-text" >-</span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder=""  />
    </div>
```

[ideal structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzqmK.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is easy solution:

1. Set `border` for inputs to `0` to make them invisible.
2. Add `border 1px` with color you need to parent div.
3. Don't forget to make this parent div `display: inline-block;`

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

input.form-control {
  border: 0;
  padding: 2px;
}

.input-group {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="form-realname" class="col">test*</label>
    <div class="input-group col">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" />
        <span class="input-group-text" >-</span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder=""  />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Also you should better to add more css to make `:active` state more clean.